# initialize 3D float array with return from stbi_loadf?

Tags: c++, stb-image

I'm a novice at C++., and I have a pretty simple program I'm working on and getting stuck. I'm using `stb_image` to load a `png file` from disk.

And I want to lay it out in memory so that pixel (x,y) is located at `p[y*width + x]`. not sure how to initialize the array though.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

static const int w = 4096, h = 4096;
int width, height, bpp;


float *rgb = stbi_loadf("/home/proscans/Desktop/test_norm.png", &width, &height, &bpp, 3);

float normal[w*h*3] = {...???};

return 0;



}
```

curious what should go in the braces to initialize.
can anyone weigh in?

thanks

Comment: `p[y*width + x]` is different from `NxNx3`. You need to decide. Do you want a 1 or a 3 dimension array?

Comment: sorry you're right that was a typo... 1 dim...

Comment: i can provide the complete code if anyone needs more context... this is just a snippet of what's in question...

Comment: `rgb` array(it is not actually an array) is exactly layout as you want.

Comment: Each (x, y) pixel is located at `rgb[ y * width * 3 + x * 3 ] = R, rgb[ y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 1 ] = G, rgb[ y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 2 ] = B`